# MyPy: Module "src.some..nested.folder.python_file" has no attribute "attribute_thats_definetely_there" [attr-defined]

Tags: python, mypy

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
root
├── src
│   ├── some
│   │   ├── nested
│   │   │   ├── folder
│   │   │   |   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   |   ├── python_file.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
├── tests
│   ├── folder
│   │   ├── test_python_file.py
```

With `python_file.py` containing:

```py
attribute_thats_definetely_there= ""
```

And `test_python_file.py` containing:

```py
from src.some.nested.folder.schemas.python_file import attribute_thats_definetely_there
```

And for some reason mypy is throwing the error:

```
Module "src.some.nested.folder.schemas.python_file" has no attribute "attribute_thats_definetely_there"  [attr-defined]
```

Even though the code executes perfectly.

I've been trying to find some setting that works, my `pyproject.toml` file looks like this:

```ini
[tool.mypy]
python_version = "3.10"
namespace_packages = true
allow_redefinition = true
show_error_codes = true
disallow_untyped_defs = true
ignore_missing_imports = true
```

And I've tried looking at answers and different possible argument configurations, but nothing seems to do the job. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Why do you have `.schemas` in your import path when doesn't exist in your file directory?

Comment: Is the variable actually defined at the top level of the module, or does it get defined by a function that needs to be called before the variable exists?